# How to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{\log{x}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\log{x}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{x}{\log{x}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=
-\frac{1}{\log{x}}\cdot\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
and remember that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Either l'Hôpital's theorem or Bernoulli inequality $$\ln (1+y)\le y $$ for $ y =\dfrac 1 {x-1} $.

Comment: The mistake in Bernoulli's inequality was a typo, calm the Hell down!

Answer (score 0):

Changing variable $x=\frac 1y$ makes $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{\log{x}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(1-y)}{y\log(y)}$$ Now, remembering that, for small values of $y$, $$\log(1-y)=-y-\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ $$\frac{\log(1-y)}{y\log(y)}=\frac{-y-\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right) }{y\log(y)}=-\frac{1+\frac{y}{2}+O\left(y^2\right) }{\log(y)}\approx -\frac{1}{\log(y)}\to 0^+$$